# How to use a third party SDK in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am new in React dev and web dev in general.

There is an SDK that has been built by a third party and that would be downloadable like the following in a "standard web development language"

HTML Page :

```
<script src="https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js"></script>
```

In the page where I want to use this third party function :

```
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
```

The code part to personalize the object I am using from that third party :

```
var player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"),{ 
video: "x7tgad0", 
width: "100%", 
height: "100%", 
params: { 
    autoplay: true, 
    mute: true 
}
```

});

Usually, to use a third-party "Component" in React, I download it using npm install. But here, it is not in npm.

How would you do to use it?

Thanks!

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution.

Here is the main idea :

In order to use the API script (which is a video player), we can first create a React component and use it afterwars. This is how that component should (in my solution) be :

```
class DMPlayer extends Component {*your code here*}
```

In the component you will neer a render method :

```
render () {  return (<div id="player"></div>);}
```

The div here has an id to which the API/SDK will point. But this will depend on the API/SDK you want to use.

The main information that allowed me to solution this issue is the use of DOM and window in a ComponentDidMount method as follows :

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const DM = document.createElement('script');
    DM.setAttribute('src', 'https://api.dmcdn.net/all.js');

    let player //we define a variable here but we put something in it after as the code has to donwload first

    DM.addEventListener('load', () => {
      player = window.DM.player //Here we use the window to recover the downloaded script

      player(document.getElementById("player"),{ 
        video: "x7tgad0", 
        width: "100%", 
        height: "100%", 
        params: { 
            autoplay: true, 
            mute: true 
        } 
      }); 
      
    });
  
    document.body.appendChild(DM); //add everithing to the DOM
  }
```